# Is there an available repository to update OpenSSH to 4.8+ on Centos 5.4?

Tags: centos, sftp, ssh, chroot

I need OpenSSH 4.8+ in order to do setup a clean chrooted SFTP on my Centos 5.4 with Remi and EPEL repositories.

Is there a repository for Centos which contain an updated OpenSSH?

Thanks!

---

**Extra info :**

I want OpenSSH 4.8+ in order to not install an extra library (RSSH) when OpenSSH can already handle it. However if you think that there is a cleaner and easier to maintain way to install a chrooted SFTP server let me know!

Comment: Why not compile from source or create your own package?

Comment: Compiling from source or creating my own package don't seems to be the easier to maintain. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to create your own OpenSSH package for CentOS because the OpenSSH source distribution contains an RPM spec file. Follow [these instructions](http://binblog.info/2009/02/27/packaging-openssh-on-centos/) and grab the sources from [here](http://openssh.org/portable.html).

Comment: From the instructions linked to by nlo: March 30, 2010: It was pointed out to me that Redhat has backported chroot functionality into its OpenSSH 4.3 packages, so these directions may not be neccessary anymore. Maybe the chroot bits needed have been backported?